# Haskell Recursive Adding Function Not Working

Tags: haskell, recursion

I attempted to write a Haskell function to recursively determine if a list is under a arbitrary value. For some reason, the code is not compiling. My error is below.

```
--declare function
checkIfExpensive :: [Float] -> Float -> String

--base case
checkIfExpensive [] x = "You have enough money"
checkIfExpensive list x = if x > 20
--recursive case
                                then "You don't have enough money"
                                else checkIfExpensive (init list) (last list + x)
```

EDIT: got code to compile by switching where I had 'tail' to 'last'. But, now I seem to get a different error everytime I run my code.

Here is what some of the errors look like

```
*Main> checkIfExpensive [5,5,5] 0

<interactive>:1:1: error: Data constructor not in scope: Ixve5
*Main> checkIfExpensive [1,1,1] 0

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: cpe
Prelude>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're typing exactly what you intend? As you say,  those errors make no sense given your intended input - but the variable names it's complaining about are made up of characters from the intended input, in order. So it's almost like your keyboard is broken and missing some characters don't display? (But then I don't know how you typed your post, including the sample GHCi session...)

Comment: There is no way you would get these errors from this command. If you had something not in scope in your program, it would say it when it loads your program, not when you type the command.

Answer (score 0):

The tail of a list denotes everything after the first element in the list. 
For example, the tail of [1, 2, 3, 4] would simply be [2, 3, 4]. The error you have received is sensibly informing you that you cannot add a float to a list of floats.

The implementation of the tail function is made clear by considering the inductive definition of the list data-type, i.e. a list is either empty or is constructed with an element and a list.

One way you might have spotted this issue earlier is to observe the type of tail, which is as follows:

```
tail :: [a] -> [a]
```

The correct way to obtain the last element of a list is with the last function, with the following type signature:

```
last :: [a] -> a
```

I also recommend using the `all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` function for checking whether a condition holds for an entire list. For example, given a list of floats `xs`, you can use:

```
all (<= 20) xs
```

Alternatively, there is also `any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`. Additionally, the idiomatic way to recurse over a list is to pattern match on the head and the tail, for example:

```
checkIfExpensive :: [Float] -> String
checkIfExpensive [] = "You have enough money"
checkIfExpensive (x:xs)
  | x > 20 = "You don't have enough money"
  | otherwise = checkIfExpensive xs
```

Comment: I realized I misunderstood the tail function and swapped it for the last function. My code compiles now, but it is giving me bizarre errors now when running the function.

Answer (score 0):

First: `String` is far too "large" a type for your return value. There are only two (out of an infinite number) possible return values. Use `Bool` instead. (You can always write a separate function to select a message to display.)

```
checkIfExpensive :: [Float] -> Bool
```

Second, there is already a pre-defined function to determine if *any* element of the list satisfies your condition: the `any` function.

```
any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
```

Lists are foldable, so all you need to write is

```
checkIfExpensive list = any (\x -> x > 20) list
```

If you want to return a `String` anyway, the `if` expression can test the return value of `any`.

```
checkIfExpensive :: [Float] -> String
checkIfExpensive list = if any (\x -> x > 20) list 
                        then "You don't have enough money"
                        else "You don't have enough money"
```